# Wrong data included in before insert trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

Im trying to create a trigger `before insert` that will add data in `column1 table1` using data from `column1 table2`, but when im trying to compare id between table1 and table2 and insert, insert occurs in the next row from the desired

Here is my trigger code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER electricity_consumption_update
before insert ON electr
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
set new.electricity_consumption =  
(new.`Printer_power_VT` * new.`electricity_kVT/hr` * 
(select printing_time_hr from slicer where slicer.id = (select electr.id from electr)) * 0.001);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Here im trying to compare id of table "slicer" and "electr" before insert, but when i insert the first row, the column i want to fill by this trigger is empty, and when i insert the second row, the column i fill with the trigger is not empty but gets the data that had to be in a previous row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
= (select electr.id from electr)
```

should be

```
= new.id
```